# variable en mysqli_query

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una duda con `mysqli_query()`, ¿Como mando variables a mi `query`?

Tengo el siguiente código Pero me marca error al ejecutarlo ¿como puedo mandar los parámetros `POST` hacia mi `query`?

```
<?php
require ('conexionbd.php');

$varusr = $_POST['usr'];
$varpwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$query = "CALL validaingreso('$varusr','$varpwd')"

$result = mysqli_query($enlace,$query);

echo $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

?>
```

Comment: Y que dice el error? te falta un  ; al final de la línea de $query, si omites el ; php te saca error

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\HelpDeskSIGMX\ingreso.php on line 9

Comment: Si ingreso sin variables y dejo las validaciones si funciona, pero quiero pasarle las variables pero no se como concatenarlas hacia mi consulta

Comment: Y ya agregaste el ;?

Comment: El error que recibes es porque falta el `;` como indica @CamiloVasquez en sus comentarios. Esto es un error tipográfico.

Answer (score 4):

Debes concadenar tus variables con puntos, te muestro como debería ser tu consulta:

```
$query = "CALL validaingreso('" . $varusr . "','" . $varpwd . "')";  
$result = mysqli_query($enlace,$query);
```

Nota como se cierran las comillas cada que concadenarás una variable, con esto indicas a PHP que es texto y que es código, y con el punto indicas concadenación de textos por lo que PHP lo traduce como "a este texto agrégale el valor de esta variable"

Comment: Ya pude resolverlo, me funciono de esta manera:                      $varusr = $_POST['usr'];
 $varpwd = $_POST['pwd'];
 
 $query = ("CALL validaingreso('$varusr','$varpwd')");

Comment: No obstante, este código es vulnerable a la Inyección de código malicioso. Deber implementar **consultas preparadas**. Para más detalles puedes consultar: **[¿Cómo evitar la Inyección SQL en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)**

Comment: eso es muy cierto @a-cedano

Comment: Esto no puede ser la solución. Como el usuario está usando comillas dobles, la versión de la pregunta y la de la respuesta son equivalentes. El problema era otro.

Comment: Exacto @AlvaroMontoro sigo insistiendo en que el error era la falta de ; ....

Answer (score 2):

La forma de resolver tu problema de forma definitiva sería implementando **consultas preparadas**, ya que enviar esta consulta `$query = ("CALL validaingreso('$varusr','$varpwd')");` para que se ejecute directamente es un grave agujero de seguridad.

Veamos cómo implementar consultas preparadas en este caso, explicando dos posibles formas de hacerlo: usando el estilo procedural (el que implementas en tu código)  y el estilo orientado a objetos (que es más moderno y más comprensible). De todos modos, ambos funcionan igual.

### A. Estilo procedural

```
$varusr = $_POST['usr']; 
$varpwd = $_POST['pwd']; 
$query = ("CALL validaingreso(?,?)");

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($enlace, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $varusr, $varpwd);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
echo $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

### B. Estilo orientado a objetos

```
$varusr = $_POST['usr']; 
$varpwd = $_POST['pwd']; 
$query = ("CALL validaingreso(?,?)");

$stmt = $enlace->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $varusr, $varpwd);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();
echo $row_cnt = $stmt->num_rows();

$stmt->close();
```

---

### Breve explicación del código

- En la instrucción SQL sustituimos las variables que antes se pasaban de manera directa por marcadores de posición `?`. Este es el primer paso para neutralizar el ataque
- Luego usamos `prepare` para decirle al manejador que nos prepare esa consulta.
- Acto seguido pasamos los valores aparte mediante `bind_param`. Este es el segundo paso para neutralizar la inyección. Las `ss` que hay en el código significan que las dos columnas usadas en este caso son del tipo `VARCHAR` en la base de datos. Si por ejemplo alguna de ellas fuese del tipo `INT` tendríamos que poner una `i` en vez de la `s`. También es importante señalar que en el `bind_param` las variables deben ponerse en el orden que les corresponda en `$query`. Y lo mismo aplica al tipo de dato.
- Cuando tenemos todo listo, invocamos a `execute` para que termine el trabajo.
- El Manual de PHP indica que, al usar consultas preparadas, si queremos obtener el total de filas devueltas, primero debemos invocar a `store_result`.
- Finalmente, cerramos la variable `$stmt`.